# Estimating with a Taylor Polynomial of an Indefinite Integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So I correctly found the MacLaurin series for $\int \sin(x^2)dx$, but I don't know what to plug into the polynomial to estimate the integral from $0$ to $1$. I don't think I do one set of the polynomial at 1, and another at 0, because I tried that and the answer does not match the key.

EDIT:
It tells me to use the first 3 terms of my series (these terms have already been integrated):
$x-\frac{x^7}{7*3!}+\frac{x^{11}}{11*5!}$

Comment: Since $\sin(x)$ expansion starts with $x$, $\sin(x^2)$ expansion starts with $x^2$ and the integral must start with $\frac 13 x^3$. You next terms are correct.

Comment: I think that would be it. I can't believe I started with a 1 instead of an $x$. Then would that whole polynomial just be evaluated at 1-0? i.e.
$[\frac{(1)^3}{3}-\frac{(1)^7}{7*3!}+\frac{(1)^{11}}{11*5!}]-[\frac{(0)^3}{3}-\frac{(0)^7}{7*3!}+\frac{(0)^{11}}{11*5!}]$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = sin(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n(((-1)^n/(2n+1)!)x^n $ Taylor Polynome for f(x) = sin(x) Taylor Expansion for $f(x)=sin(x)$

if $f(u) = sin(u), u = x^2, then,   f (x^2) =\sum_{i=0}^n(((-1)^n/(2n+1)!)(x^2)^n $

Integrating:

$\int_{0}^1 f(x^2) dx$
$\int_{0}^1 \sum_{i=0}^n(((-1)^n/(2n+1)!)(x^2)^n  dx$

Expand the polynomial expression whatever do you want, integrate it and then evaluate from 0 to 1.